# Feature selection with a binary dependent variable

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, python

Given we have a binary dependent variable and 100s of features and ~50k observations, is there a generally accepted way to trim the features via some type of machine learning concept? I was trying a Lasso regression to zero out features, but it just showed nothing was significant. I can go through multiple by hand that are definitely significant, though, so I must be doing something wrong. If I had a specific type of selection to look into, I would feel more comfortable learning about that specific concept and knowing it should theoretically work for me.

Sorry I'm a complete noob to this, and am just looking for some general direction.

Comment: Elaborate your question. What is your coding language? Add a snippet of your code so we can take a look at the input and output to give better insights

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are using python, but sklearn's documentation has a few good suggestions on commonly used feature selection techniques: 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html

You also may want to look into decomposition techniques such as principal components analysis (PCA) and partial least squares (PLS).